# security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext Error - Unable to Install Delve on MacOS

Tags: macos, go, homebrew, zsh, delve

I installed Delve using:

```
brew install delve
```

The log shows some issues:

```
brew install go-delve/delve/delve
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing delve from go-delve/delve
==> Downloading https://github.com/derekparker/delve/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/delve-1.0.0.tar.gz
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
==> Generating dlv-cert
==> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -config dlv-cert.cfg -extensions codesign_reqext -batch -out dlv-cert.cer -keyout dlv-cert.key
==> [SUDO] Installing dlv-cert as root
==> sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain dlv-cert.cer
```

It didn't install since when running the command `dlv`  I get the error:

> zsh: command not found: dlv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by following these steps:

```
cd $HOME/Library/Caches/Homebrew
tar xf delve-*.gz
Go into the new directory (mine is delve-1.0.0)
sh scripts/gencert.sh and enter your password
brew install go-delve/delve/delve
```